# X11 standard file chooser dialog

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xcb

Is there such thing as a standard file chooser (and file save) dialogs in X? If yes, what's the extension/request for invoking that? If no, does that mean that Qt, GTK, wxWidgets, etc. each implement their own with different look and behavior, so I must do the same?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK X11 has no standard widgets at all.

Comment: The short and only answer is *no*. X11 doesn't have standard *anything*, it's all up to the applications and window managers to use whatever widget-kits they fancy. The basic core of X11 is simply a networked protocol to draw on surfaces, and that's about it.

Comment: X is not a display manager nor an gui toolkit. It "only" is a server which accepts drawing commands ( and a lot more for configuration and also all the input handling and so on). It is simply a layer between graphics hardware and the UI stuff. If you look for UI stuff you should look for a gui toolkit. fltk is very smart and transparent to X.

Comment: So basically in Linux where there's Qt apps and GTK apps and wxWidgets apps and FLTK apps, every one of those toolkits have to implement their own file chooser dialogs with different layout and behavior, eternally confusing the user?

Comment: @cap wxWidgets use other libraries to display its widgets, so that solves this problem somewhat. And yes, other libraries implement their own solution, and that's a good thing, different toolkits and DEs have different goals, so a one size fits for all approach is not applicable.

Comment: these comments are very helpful in making me understand why Linux has no market share on the Desktop. thank you! I guess I'll just randomly choose either Qt's or GTK's file dialogs for my app, in hope of pleasing at least 50% of the user base.

Comment: @cap lol. If you make a Qt app, use Qt, if you make a GTK app, then use GTK+. By the way for interop reasons in GTK+ DEs, Qt apps render using a GTK+ theme, and vice versa. (And FLTK looks the same horrible way across all platforms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X11 does not have any standard widgets, graphics toolkits implement these features on top of the X display server. X is only responsible of *displaying*, while toolkits are responsible for *drawing*, two different responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/x42/sofd

"SOFD is a rather simple dialog window to allow a user to choose a file. It is intended to be used in cross-platform toolkit-less programs (such as audio plugins) to provide a file dialog for X11/unix systems, where other platforms have a similar dialog from the operating system."